# Cannot start qutebrowser, installed packages are shown as missing

Tags: pip, installation

I'm trying to install qutebrowser with tox and followed the instructions on [this](https://github.com/qutebrowser/qutebrowser/blob/master/doc/install.asciidoc#tox) page.
However, this didn't work. When I run

```
python3 -m qutebrowser
```

I get one of the error messages

```
Fatal error: jinja2 is required to run qutebrowser but could not be imported! Maybe it's not installed?

The error encountered was:
No module named 'jinja2'

Please search for the python3 version of jinja2 in your distributions packages, or see https://github.com/qutebrowser/qutebrowser/blob/master/doc/install.asciidoc

If you installed a qutebrowser package for your distribution, please report this as a bug.
```

or the same with `PyYAML/yaml` instead of `jinja2`.

However, if I run

```
sudo pip install jinja2
sudo pip install pyyaml
```

I get

```
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (2.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from jinja2) (0.23)

Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (5.1)
```

I guess the problem may be that the installed versions are for python2.7, however I followed [these](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) instructions without change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You followed *those* instructions with a change: you run `python3` instead of `python`.

If you have both Python 2.7 and Python 3 installed to install packages for Python 3 you need to run `pip3 install` or `python3 -m pip install`.